# CSS 2 columns grid to 2 rows

Tags: html, css

Almost 2 weeks later, countless tries later, even asking a similar question before, I can't make something so simple. CSS doesn't return any info as we know, therefore I don't even know why.

All the examples that I find work, they work on their own, or with media query, while mine, never acts as I want it to, even if I copy the solution. The grids do shrink, and only that happens, no new row ever appears anywhere.

I simplified my design, my website grew over almost those 2 weeks, and I'm sharing just the minimum here, so someone can maybe tell me why grid never adjusts itself, regardless of everything. I want to achieve a very simple thing.

Top consists of 2 columns [top_left + top_right], and I want them to change into 2 rows at a certain screen width, same applies to bottom part [bot_left + bot_right]. In theory and practice, this is doable with both media query and without. No media queries using auto-fill seems to be a better option, because it just adjusts on its own to the screen size, making everything simpler, I guess.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top_left"></div>
    <div class="top_right"></div>
    <div class="top_mid"> </div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="bot_left"></div>
    <div class="bot_right"></div>
    <div class="bot"></div>
 </div>
```

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   background-color: #E6E6E3;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container {   
   height: 100%;
   display: grid; 
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 
   grid-template-rows: auto;
   gap: 0px;
} 
   .top_left {
      height: 100px; 
      display: grid;
      background-color: white;
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end: 2;
      grid-row-start: 1; 
      grid-row-end: 2;
      border: 1px solid red;
}
   .top_mid {
      display: grid;
      background-color: #36454F;
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end: 3;
      grid-row-start: 2;
      grid-row-end: 3;
}
   .top_right {
      height: 100px; 
      display: grid;
      background-color: white; 
      grid-column-start: 2;
      grid-column-end: 3;
      grid-row-start: 1; 
      grid-row-end: 2;
      border: 1px solid blue;
}
   .main {
      max-width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
      display: grid;
      background-color: white; 
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end: 3;
      grid-row-start: 3; 
      grid-row-end: 5;
      border-left: 1px solid #78BE21;
      border-right: 1px solid #78BE21;
}
   .bot_left {
      height: 150px; 
      display: grid;
      background-color: #BCD9ED; 
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end: 2;
      grid-row-start: 5;
      grid-row-end: 6;
      border-top: 1px solid #191919;      
      border-bottom: 1px solid #191919;
}
   .bot_right {
      height: 150px; 
      display: grid;
      background-color: #7F8778; 
      grid-column-start: 2;
      grid-column-end: 3;
      grid-row-start: 5;
      grid-row-end: 6;
      border-top: 1px solid #191919;      
      border-bottom: 1px solid #191919;
}
   .bot {
      height: 250px; 
      display: grid;
      background-color: deepskyblue;
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end: 3;
      grid-row-start: 6;
      grid-row-end: 8;
}
```

Comment: Haven't you tried `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr))`?
With auto-fit empty tracks will be collapsed while auto-fill will preserve them

Comment: Yes, many things, I have multiple pages added to favorite. I tried what you just added, fit, fill, queries, min max, no row appears. It either shrinks, gets longer, or the entire page gets smaller, but no extra row. I'm starting to think there is something wrong in the code that prevents from the row creation. I wonder if the column start/end, row start/end is the reason. No example that I saw used it. They have no predefined grid position. There is a container a bunch of divs not much else.

Comment: Yes, the behaviour seems to be connected with the predefined position + there'll be more rows on smaller screens. The only thing I can think if: wrap left/right top divs and left\right bot ones into separate fluid grid containers